# MySQL: Load data infile and ignore tab in file

Tags: linux, mysql, command-line-interface

MySQL command I have so far:

```
 load data infile 'data.txt' into table foo (column_foobar);
```

data.txt:

```
    bar1
    bar2
    bar3
```

Note the tab at beginning of each line. How can I ignore the tab with MySQL so that bar1, bar2, bar3 gets loaded in column_foobar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to use the [LINES STARTING BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) clause

```
load data infile 'data.txt' into table foo LINES STARTING BY '\t'  (foobar);
```

which will do what you want for that data provided. If your data was for example

```
bar1
bar2
bar3    bar4
```

with a tab between `bar3` and `bar4` then you would have to use something like

```
load data infile 'data.txt' into table foo 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n'
LINES STARTING BY '\t'  (foobar);
```

Comment: Very good answer. As it turns out I hadn't tabs in my data.txt file, but four spaces, so I ended up using four phyiscal spaces instead of the \t, which worked great!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just remove the leading tabs with `sed 's/^<tab goes here>//'` before loading the file?

If you (in bash) push `Ctrl+V` and then `TAB`, you will get a tab in the shell that sed can remove.

Comment: That would add one more step in processing my files. So I prefer lain's solution.